# how many teams can be assigned to a task such that at least one team completes a task

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

There's a problem in my combinatorics class: there're 5 people who need to complete 4 tasks. They decided that each task will be completed by a team of 2 people. In how many ways can we assign a team to a task if it's not allowed that there will be a person which didn't do any task? The problem has to be solved using inclusion-exclusion principle (IEP).

I have trouble solving the problem but this is what I have so far:
1) we can choose the teams in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways which equals $10$. All of the tasks can theoretically by completed by only one team so we have $10^4$ possibilities. 
2) using IEP let's subtract from $10^4$ the case where at least one team will not complete any tasks ($9^4$) etc. So we would get something like this:
$$10^4-9^4+8^4-7^4+6^4-5^4+4^4-3^4+2^4-1^4=5995$$

Am I in the right direction?

Comment: Not following.  There are $\frac {5\times 4}2=10$ two person teams.  It is not possible to give each of them a task (given that there are fewer than $10$ tasks).

Comment: Did you possibly mean "such that no person goes without an assigned task"?

Comment: @lulu you're right "such that no person goes without a task"

Comment: Fine.  As you say, there are $10^4$ assignments if we ignore the constraint.  How many of them miss person $A$?  Well, with only four people there'd be $\frac {4\times 3}2=6$ teams so $6^4$.  But there's persons $B,C,D,E$ to consider.  Thus the first subtraction should be $5\times 6^4$.  Now you have to add back the assignments that miss two people, and so on.

Comment: @lulu   I think you're right, one of my problems was that I was considering the number of teams while I should've focused on people. Is this full solution correct?  $$10^4 - \binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{2}^4 + \binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}^4 - \binom{5}{3}\binom{2}{2}^4$$

Comment: That looks good!

Comment: This is a (minimum) vertex cover problem.  How many ways you can pick (4) edges on a five point set so that all points are included.

Answer (score 1):

As you figured out in the comments, there are $\binom5k$ ways to choose $k$ people to miss, $\binom{5-k}2$ ways to choose teams for the remaining people, and thus $\binom{5-k}2^4$ ways to assign teams to the $4$ tasks without these $k$ people, so by inclusion–exclusion the number of admissible team assignments is

$$
\sum_{k=0}^3(-1)^k\binom5k\binom{5-k}2^4=4320\;.
$$